# Does NavOptionsBuilder.launchSingleTop work with nested navigation graphs in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, navigation-compose

I'm using `BottomNavigation` in Jetpack Compose with `navigation-compose:2.5.0-alpha04` and I want to encapsulate each tab's flow with [nested navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav). To achieve this I created a single NavHost with different graphs inside:

```kotlin
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = defaultTab.route
    ) {
        eventsGraph()

        employeesGraph()

        devicesGraph()

        feedbackGraph()
    }
```

Each graph contains its own `composable`s inside a `navigation` extension function.

As [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav) suggest, when `BottomNavigationItem` is clicked, I'm configuring my `NavOptions` the following way:

```kotlin
onClick = {
    navController.navigate(tab.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
            saveState = true
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        // We want to reset the graph if it is clicked while already selected
        restoreState = tab != currentTab
    }
    currentTab = tab
}
```

I'm expecting this code to ignore clicks on an already selected item and always having any selected tab as nav graph's root, i.e. quitting the app on back press if user is at the root destination of any given tab.

Instead, every click on a default tab at its start destination puts another instance of the same destination in the stack, and back press at a non-default tab puts me back to the `defaultTab`'s destination.

I tried popping destinations `inclusive`, but `NavController` unsurprisingly just can't find saved `Destination`'s ID to restore state for. I tried to `saveState` by the same `tab != currentTab` condition by which I restore it, but it appears to have no effect.

Is it possible to achieve desired behavior by the means of Navigation APIs or do I need to handle this by myself?

### Update

I eventually came up with the following solution for resetting the current tab's graph. Basically, instead of navigating with `popUpTo` option we're just popping the stack to the start destination.

```kotlin
onClick = {
    if (tab == currentTab) {
        navController.popBackStack(
            route = tab.startDestination,
            inclusive = false
        )
        return@BottomNavigationItem
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

There is still an issue with `defaultTab`'s graph being the root, which means pressing the back button on any non-defalut tab's start does not exit the app.

Comment: If you just want to do nothing if you're reselecting the tab you are already on, is there a reason you're not just doing `if (tab != currentTab) { navController.navigate(...) }`?

Comment: This prevents resetting tab's graph on selected tab click, which is a behavior I want.

Comment: So if `tab == currentTab`, you want to pop everything up to the root of that stack?

Comment: Yes. I managed to achieve that. See edit

Comment: Did you get a chance to read the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) that specifically states that you should never surprise the user by exiting the app from anything but the start destination of your app?

Comment: Apparently, I did not. Thank you for pointing it out. I will post an answer addressing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you need to write this logic by yourself. Fortunately, most of it is handled by the navigation library.
What was required:

1. Single tab at a time in a stack
2. Tab's navigation state is saved on leave and restored on enter
3. Selected tab's navigation state is reset on click
4. Any selected tab is the root of the navigation graph

Every one of those except 4 was achieved. As [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789903/does-navoptionsbuilder-launchsingletop-work-with-nested-navigation-graphs-in-jet?noredirect=1#comment126886213_71789903), exiting the app on system back press must always happen in the start destination of the app, so I left the default behavior in place.

As for items 1-3, here's complete `onClick` implementation for `BottomNavigationItem`:

```kotlin
onClick = {
    // Handling resetting current tab's state
    if (tab == currentTab) {
        navController.popBackStack(
            route = tab.startDestination,
            inclusive = false
        )
        return@BottomNavigationItem
    }
    
    // Handling singleTop behavior with saving state
    navController.navigate(tab.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
            saveState = true
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = tab != currentTab
    }
    appBarViewModel.setCurrentTab(tab)
}
```

What is tricky about this is `currentTab` from the previous implementation is not updated when `defaultTab` is shown after system back press, so I am updating it based on current nav back stack as a side effect:

```kotlin
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
LaunchedEffect(navBackStackEntry) {
    // This condition is possible to be true if a system "Back" press was detected in a non-default tab,
    // navigating the user to app's start destination.
    // To correctly reflect that in bottom navigation, this code is needed
    if (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route == appBarViewModel.defaultTab.startDestination)
        appBarViewModel.setCurrentTab(appBarViewModel.defaultTab)
}
```